# Adding constant to QString

Tags: qt, constants, qstring

I have the following:

```
#define versions 0.9.0
```

and I want to add to QString:

```
QString str = QString("Software version %1").arg(versions);
```

this won't work. anyone know why?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#define versions "0.9.0"`

You forgot to put quotes around the version number.

Answer (score 2):

your macro is C coding style, if you are coding in C++ manner, use this:

```
const QString versions = "0.9.0";
```